# View doesn't show with "setViewController" in a UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to change the pages showed by my UIPageView programatically.

I created two ViewController that are intended to be displayed in the PageView, and I set the initial View with "setViewControllers" in my viewDidLoad. I works, the view is displayed and I can swipe on the screen to switch between the two views.

My problem being that when I try to call again "setViewControllers" to change the displayed view when I click a button, nothing happens.

I'm using delegates since the buttons are part of another ViewController, and used NSLog to make sure the functions were called, which is the case.

If anyone could help me understand why the "setViewControllers" method doesn't do anything, that would be great.

Here is my code for my **UIPageViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class FrontContentController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, sideMenuDelegate {

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex <= 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex - 1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex >= subViewControllers.count - 1 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex + 1]
    }

    lazy var subViewControllers:[UIViewController] = {
        return [
            UIStoryboard(name: "frontPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstContent") as! FirstContentController,
            UIStoryboard(name: "frontPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondContent") as! SecondContentController
        ]
    }()

    var sideMenuVC : SideMenuController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.sideMenuVC = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenu") as! SideMenuController)
        self.setViewControllers([subViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func changeColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        if color == .blue {
            self.setViewControllers([subViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
            NSLog("Blue Delegate")
        }
        if color == .red {
            self.setViewControllers([subViewControllers[1]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
            NSLog("Red Delegate")
        }
    }
}
```

And in case it's relevant, the separate **UIViewController** with the buttons (a side menu) :

```
import UIKit

protocol sideMenuDelegate: AnyObject {
    func changeColor(_ color : UIColor)
}

class SideMenuController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate : sideMenuDelegate?
    var frontPageVC : FrontPageController!
    var frontContentPC : FrontContentController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "frontPage", bundle: nil)
        frontPageVC = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FrontPage") as! FrontPageController)
        frontContentPC = (storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FrontContent") as! FrontContentController)
        self.delegate = frontContentPC
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

    @IBAction func pressBlueButton(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.changeColor(UIColor .blue)
    }
    @IBAction func pressRedButton(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.changeColor(UIColor .red)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the displayed page view controller is the same instance as the one in the `frontContentPC` property, which is used as the delegate for the `SideMenuController`?

Comment: You are right actually, I printed the memory address of `self` in the `viewDidLoad` of my **PageViewController**, and indeed when I click a button, a second address is printed.

I am now trying to understand how can I avoid that, I you have any pointers it would be appreciated.

Comment: `instantiateViewController` creates a new instance, that is why there are no visual changes after you tap a button

Comment: I understand now. I just need to figure out how can I set references the right way without creating new instances now, this part is still a bit blurry for me.